# 4 points and Ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, drawing

I have 4 points.. i can draw a polygon usign this code

```
var p = new Polygon();
p.Points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
p.Points.Add(new Point(70, 0));
p.Points.Add(new Point(90, 100));
p.Points.Add(new Point(0, 80));
```

**How i can draw an 'ellipse' that will fit in this polygon, using Silverlight?**

[image]

## Question is still unanswared!!!

Comment: If you can't find any functions or code to do this for you right away (there might be, I just don't know of them), you can read up on [this](http://chrisjones.id.au/Ellipses/ellipse.html) to give you ideas on how you can approach this.

Comment: tnx a lot for link, i'm not so good at math.. but i will try to 'get something' from this article..

Comment: Crucial info is missing: should the 'ellipse' have its axis x&y-aligned or can the axis be freely aligned? (According to your sample image one gets the impression that it should be x&y-aligned.)

Comment: Yes.. offcource XY should be aligned.. you can get this from picture..

Comment: add example with QuadraticBezierSergemts

Comment: +1. Such an interesting question.

Comment: @Otaku, totally agree.  :-)  +1 also.

Comment: look over this [http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/ellipse/](http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/ellipse/) article for calculating exact points for bezier curves.

Answer (score 9):

One way is use `QuadraticBezierSegment` or `BezierSegment`.

For example, like this:

```
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" >
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,40">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <BezierSegment Point1="0,93"
                                           Point2="90,117"
                                           Point3="80,50"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" >
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,40">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                <BezierSegment Point1="0,-13"
                                           Point2="70,-17"
                                           Point3="80,50"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
<Polygon Points="0,0 70,0 90,100 0,80"></Polygon>
```

[image: it look like this]

it's not exact solution, for exact you must colculate exact points for curves and use 4 `QuadraticBezierSegment`

**Edit:**
Example for `QuadraticBezierSegment`

```
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,40">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="6,79"
                                           Point2="45,90"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="45,90">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="80,91"
                                           Point2="80,50"
                                           />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,40">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="2,3"
                                           Point2="35,0"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="35,0">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="72,8"
                                           Point2="80,50"
                                           />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Polygon Name="pol"  Points="0,0 70,0 90,100 0,80" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"</Polygon>
```

[image: this is image of this example]

it still an experimental, not calculate point, but it quite exact.

**Edit2:**
You may calculate points of curves with use of this image and my comments:

[image]

curves have a startpoint, midle point and endpoint. In this image start and end piont are `L,M,N,O`; and midle are `W,X,Y,Z`.

How for example we calculate point `L`:

Whith help of equation of line `y = k * x + b` we find equation of line `AB,DC,AC,DB,AD`. How cross of `AC` and `DB` we find `R`. How cross of `AB` and `DC` we find `E`. After that we find equation of line `ER` and how cross of `ER` and `AD` we find `L`.

How we calculate point `W`:

Whith help of equation for length `l = sqrt(sqr(x2 - x1) + sqr(y2 - y1))` find length of `AR`. `AW = AR/(4*pi)` and whith help of this coefficient, and equation of line and equation for length, after solving of square equation we find `W`.

Other points we find similarly.

This algorithm not work only for polygon which have parallel line, but in this case algorithm is more easier. And coefficient for length are the same.

Whith help of this algorithm i find point for 3 curves of your example:

```
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,36">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="4.7,74.6"
                                           Point2="39.9,88.9"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="39.9,88.9">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="83.43,92.7"
                                           Point2="78.8,43.9"
                                           />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,36">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="3.55,3.94"
                                           Point2="31.8,0"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

And it curves exactly the same as ellipse line. Image below:

[image]

*You may translate this algorithm to 'formula' and so find your solution.*

You need 4 function for that:

1) find line coefficients from coordinates of 2 pionts

2) find coordinates of piont how cross of 2 lines from it's coefficients

3) find length of segment from coordinates of 2 points

4) find coordinates of piont whiсh lies on line with this start point and this length from line coefficients and coordinates of start point and length which you find in previous function divided by (4*pi)

**Edit3:**
*You may optimize this solution, it have some defects, how parallel line etc. But it fast and if you optimise it may satisfy your requirements.*

Xaml:

```
<Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure x:Name="pathleftdown" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="bezleftdown" Point1="0,0"
                                           Point2="0,0"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure x:Name="pathrigthdown" StartPoint="0,0">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="bezrigthdown" Point1="0,0"
                                           Point2="0,0"
                                           />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure x:Name="pathleftup"  StartPoint="0,0">
                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                            <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="bezleftup" Point1="0,0"
                                           Point2="0,0"
                                           />                                       
                            </PathSegmentCollection>
                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathFigureCollection>
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure x:Name="pathrigthup"  StartPoint="0,0">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <QuadraticBezierSegment x:Name="bezrigthup" Point1="0,0"
                                           Point2="0,0"
                                           />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <Polygon Name="pol"  Points="0,0 250,0 251,340 0,341" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"></Polygon>
    <Button Content="Generate" Width ="80" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

and code:

```
private class pointXY
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
    }
    private class lineKB
    {
        public double k;
        public double b;
        public bool flagXconst = false;
        public double xConst = 0;
    }

    private lineKB GetLineFromPonts(pointXY A, pointXY B)
    {
        lineKB line = new lineKB();
        if ((B.x - A.x) != 0)
        {
            line.k = (B.y - A.y) / (B.x - A.x);
            line.b = A.y - A.x * line.k;
        }
        else
        {
            line.xConst = A.x;
            line.flagXconst = true;
        }
        return line;
    }

    private pointXY GetPointFromLines(lineKB a, lineKB b)
    {
        pointXY point = new pointXY();
        if (a.flagXconst)
        {
            point.x = a.xConst;
            point.y = a.xConst * b.k + b.b;
        }else
            if (b.flagXconst)
            {
                point.x = b.xConst;
                point.y = b.xConst * a.k + a.b;
            }
            else
            {
                point.x = (a.b - b.b) / (b.k - a.k);
                point.y = a.k * point.x + a.b;
            }
        return point;
    }

    private double LengthOfLine(pointXY A, pointXY B)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((B.x - A.x) * (B.x - A.x) + (B.y - A.y) * (B.y - A.y));
    }

    private pointXY GetMidlePoint(pointXY S, double l, lineKB line, bool leftright)
    {
        double b = -2 * S.x - 2 * line.k * (-line.b + S.y);
        double a = (1 + line.k * line.k);
        double c = (S.x * S.x - l * l + (-line.b + S.y) * (-line.b + S.y));
        double d = b*b - 4 * a * c;
        double x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        double x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
        pointXY ret = new pointXY();
        if (leftright)
            if (x1 > S.x) ret.x = x1;
            else ret.x = x2;
        else
            if (x1 < S.x) ret.x = x1;
            else ret.x = x2;
        ret.y = line.k * ret.x + line.b;
        return ret;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pointXY A = new pointXY();
        A.x = pol.Points[0].X;
        A.y = pol.Points[0].Y;
        pointXY B = new pointXY();
        B.x = pol.Points[1].X;
        B.y = pol.Points[1].Y;
        pointXY C = new pointXY();
        C.x = pol.Points[2].X;
        C.y = pol.Points[2].Y;
        pointXY D = new pointXY();
        D.x = pol.Points[3].X;
        D.y = pol.Points[3].Y;
        lineKB AC = GetLineFromPonts(A, C);
        lineKB BD = GetLineFromPonts(B, D);
        pointXY R = GetPointFromLines(AC, BD);

        lineKB AB = GetLineFromPonts(A, B);
        lineKB BC = GetLineFromPonts(B, C);
        lineKB CD = GetLineFromPonts(C, D);
        lineKB DA = GetLineFromPonts(D, A);

        pointXY E = GetPointFromLines(AB, CD);
        lineKB ER = GetLineFromPonts(E, R);
        pointXY L = GetPointFromLines(ER, DA);
        pointXY N = GetPointFromLines(ER, BC);

        pointXY F = GetPointFromLines(BC, DA);
        lineKB FR = GetLineFromPonts(F, R);
        pointXY M = GetPointFromLines(FR, AB);
        pointXY O = GetPointFromLines(FR, CD);

        pointXY W = GetMidlePoint(A, (LengthOfLine(A, R) / (4 * Math.PI)), AC, true);
        pointXY X = GetMidlePoint(B, (LengthOfLine(B, R) / (4 * Math.PI)), BD, false);
        pointXY Y = GetMidlePoint(C, (LengthOfLine(C, R) / (4 * Math.PI)), AC, false);
        pointXY Z = GetMidlePoint(D, (LengthOfLine(D, R) / (4 * Math.PI)), BD, true);

        pathleftup.StartPoint = new Point(L.x, L.y);
        bezleftup.Point1 = new Point(W.x, W.y);
        bezleftup.Point2 = new Point(M.x, M.y);

        pathleftdown.StartPoint = new Point(L.x, L.y);
        bezleftdown.Point1 = new Point(Z.x, Z.y);
        bezleftdown.Point2 = new Point(O.x, O.y);

        pathrigthdown.StartPoint = new Point(O.x, O.y);
        bezrigthdown.Point1 = new Point(Y.x, Y.y);
        bezrigthdown.Point2 = new Point(N.x, N.y);

        pathrigthup.StartPoint = new Point(M.x, M.y);
        bezrigthup.Point1 = new Point(X.x, X.y);
        bezrigthup.Point2 = new Point(N.x, N.y);

    }
```

Comment: could you make a simple example with QuadraticBezierSergemts, i tried to to this by my self but result is not so good :(

Comment: @Ai_boy Ok, i add it later, and add comment to you post when add.

Comment: @Ai_boy i try to help you, if i find, than add it to my answer

Comment: You put _quite_ a bit of work into this. Thanks for giving us your best :)

Comment: @Tim Post Thanks for undo the wiki)

Comment: Well.. i tried you solution.. it's not 'good' but i can live with it for now.. (i can clearly see 'connections' bitwin those 4 segments), I apriciate your effort, fo i will reward you... but qestion is still unanswared)

Comment: @Ai_boy You can see 'connections' bitwin those 4 segments, because calculating of middle points not exact for all polygons. If I find exact solutions for this, I add it to your question)

Answer (score 5):

With the information given by Jeff M I created a function that returns an ellipse fitting in a polygon:

```
Ellipse FitEllipse(Polygon poly)
    {
        double W0 = poly.Points[0].X;
        double W1 = poly.Points[0].Y;
        double X0 = poly.Points[1].X;
        double X1 = poly.Points[1].Y;
        double Y0 = poly.Points[2].X;
        double Y1 = poly.Points[2].Y;
        double Z0 = poly.Points[3].X;
        double Z1 = poly.Points[3].Y;

        double A =  X0 * Y0 * Z1 - W0 * Y0 * Z1 - X0 * Y1 * Z0 + W0 * Y1 * Z0 - W0 * X1 * Z0 + W1 * X0 * Z0 + W0 * X1 * Y0 - W1 * X0 * Y0;
        double B =  W0 * Y0 * Z1 - W0 * X0 * Z1 - X0 * Y1 * Z0 + X1 * Y0 * Z0 - W1 * Y0 * Z0 + W1 * X0 * Z0 + W0 * X0 * Y1 - W0 * X1 * Y0;
        double C =  X0 * Y0 * Z1 - W0 * X0 * Z1 - W0 * Y1 * Z0 - X1 * Y0 * Z0 + W1 * Y0 * Z0 + W0 * X1 * Z0 + W0 * X0 * Y1 - W1 * X0 * Y0;
        double D =  X1 * Y0 * Z1 - W1 * Y0 * Z1 - W0 * X1 * Z1 + W1 * X0 * Z1 - X1 * Y1 * Z0 + W1 * Y1 * Z0 + W0 * X1 * Y1 - W1 * X0 * Y1;
        double E = -X0 * Y1 * Z1 + W0 * Y1 * Z1 + X1 * Y0 * Z1 - W0 * X1 * Z1 - W1 * Y1 * Z0 + W1 * X1 * Z0 + W1 * X0 * Y1 - W1 * X1 * Y0;
        double F =  X0 * Y1 * Z1 - W0 * Y1 * Z1 + W1 * Y0 * Z1 - W1 * X0 * Z1 - X1 * Y1 * Z0 + W1 * X1 * Z0 + W0 * X1 * Y1 - W1 * X1 * Y0;
        double G =  X0 * Z1 - W0 * Z1 - X1 * Z0 + W1 * Z0 - X0 * Y1 + W0 * Y1 + X1 * Y0 - W1 * Y0;
        double H =  Y0 * Z1 - X0 * Z1 - Y1 * Z0 + X1 * Z0 + W0 * Y1 - W1 * Y0 - W0 * X1 + W1 * X0;
        double I =  Y0 * Z1 - W0 * Z1 - Y1 * Z0 + W1 * Z0 + X0 * Y1 - X1 * Y0 + W0 * X1 - W1 * X0;

        double detT = A * E * I + B * F * G + C * D * H - A * F * H - B * D * I - C * E * G;

        double J = (E * I - F * H) / detT;
        double K = (C * H - B * I) / detT;
        double L = (B * F - C * E) / detT;
        double M = (F * G - D * I) / detT;
        double N = (A * I - C * G) / detT;
        double O = (C * D - A * F) / detT;
        double P = (D * H - E * G) / detT;
        double Q = (B * G - A * H) / detT;
        double R = (A * E - B * D) / detT;

        double a = J * J + M * M + P * P;
        double b = J * K + M * N - P * Q;
        double c = K * K + N * N - Q * Q;
        double d = J * L + M * O - P * R;
        double f = K * L + N * O - Q * R;
        double g = L * L + O * O - R * R;

        double Ex = (c * d - b * f) / (b * b - a * c);
        double Ey = (a * f - b * d) / (b * b - a * c);

        double Ea = Math.Sqrt(2.0 * (a * f * f + c * d * d + g * b * b - 2.0 * b * d * f - a * c * g) / ((b * b - a * c) * (Math.Sqrt((a - c) * (a - c) + 4.0 * b * b) - (a + c))));
        double Eb = Math.Sqrt(2.0 * (a * f * f + c * d * d + g * b * b - 2.0 * b * d * f - a * c * g) / ((a * c - b * b) * (Math.Sqrt((a - c) * (a - c) + 4.0 * b * b) + (a + c))));

        double phi = 0;

        if (b == 0 && a < c) {
            phi = 0;
        } else if (b == 0 && a > c) {
            phi = Math.PI / 2;
        } else if (b != 0 && a < c) {
            phi = (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Atan((a - c) / (2 * b))) / 2;
        } else if (b != 0 && a > c) {
            phi = (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Atan((a - c) / (2 * b))) / 2 + Math.PI / 2;
        }

        Ellipse el = new Ellipse();
        el.Height = Ea * 2;
        el.Width  = Eb * 2;

        el.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(phi * 180 / Math.PI);

        return el;
    }
```

Comment: Wow, you made a lot of work. Man you awsome :) But it's "overkilling" in my point of view.. and also "render transform".. i don't think that browser will handle a lot this kind of "ellipses"

Comment: I can only keep track of 4 meaningless variable-names at a time.

Comment: +1 @Ai_boy I don't see how this is overkill at all. Looks like exactly what you want and RenderTransforms should be cheap enough.

Comment: and if i draw 5000 of those 'ellipses' each second, it will render fast? *irony* you soulution is perfect.. but not in my case, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

Although four bezier curves should do it quite fine (and is probably the simplest solution), I am proposing a different method here, just for kicks.  :-)

Think of your problem this way: Given a regular rectangle, draw an ellipse inside, then *deform* the rectangle into your final shape.

I don't think your deform transformation is linear, so you probably can't simply find a matrix for it (note: I may be wrong, and would love to be proven wrong; any math buffs here?)  Also see edit below.

One method is: draw your ellipse, then pull/push each of the four corners one by one.  By deforming only one corner of a shape, you can always interpolate any point on the ellipse curve to its new position by keeping the diagonal between the left and right corners intact.

EDIT: TRANSFORM

Start with a square (and a circle inside).

1. Rotate by 45 degress such that the diagonals are axes
2. Scale both axes to the right scales so that they match the relative lengths of the new shape's two diagonals
3. Skew one axis to the angle between the two diagonals of the new shape
4. Translate one axis to make the origin point match the crossing-point of the new shape's diagonals

Notice that all four transformations are either pure linear or affine (i.e. linear + translation), so they are each representable with a transformation matrix.  The end result is another affine transformation, which can also be represented by a matrix.

So your circle shape gets transformed by this matrix into the new shape.

I hope I haven't made a mistake in my math...

Comment: Well that's may be a solution.. but i think Matrix transformation wouldn't be so fast.. anyway, you have an intresting idia here, i try to implement it, but i'm not good at math

Comment: +1 It's not linear, but [projective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Perspective_projection); so you could still find a (4x4) matrix for it.

Comment: Really?  I though that projective transformation cannot handle arbitrary translations on all four corners...  i.e. the four transformed corners must still obey certain mathematical relationship...  :-)

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft, you are probably right.  It could be projective (though I can't prove it yet).  +1 anyway.

Comment: @Ai_boy, matrix transforms are the fastest, *if you can find a matrix that works*.  WPF works with DirectX on the GPU, and internally everything works on transformation matrices.  It is all done in hardware.

Comment: But GPU **not always** work in Silverlight (depend on hardware), and right now there is absolutly no GPU support for Moonlight 2, i just can't use solution that wouldn't work 'everywere'.

Comment: @Ai_boy, Silverlight falls back to software rendering when GPU is not available.  So you don't need to worry about it.  Anything that runs on a GPU will run without a GPU.  Matrix manipulations are still the fastest since software rendering in Silverlight is still heavily vector/matrix based.  Also, it leverages the SIMD instructions of the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small bug in Karsten's code around

```
} else if (b != 0 && a < c) {
    phi = (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Atan((a - c) / (2 * b))) / 2;
} else if (b != 0 && a > c) {
```

It returns phi = 0 when a==c, which is incorrect. Instead, the above lines should be

```
} else if (b != 0 && a < c) {
    phi = (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Atan((a - c) / (2 * b))) / 2;
} else if (b != 0 && a >= c) {
```

or

```
} else if (b != 0 && a <= c) {
     phi = (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Atan((a - c) / (2 * b))) / 2;
} else if (b != 0 && a > c) {
```